# Concatenating a variable and a string literal without a space in PowerShell

Tags: string, powershell

How can I write a variable to the console without a space after it? There are problems when I try:

```
$MyVariable = "Some text"
Write-Host "$MyVariableNOSPACES"
```

I'd like the following output:

```
Some textNOSPACES
```

Comment: Yeah, for all the un/boxing shortcuts Powershell *cough* "enables", you'd think that, unless you have a variable named `$MyVariableN` (or another collision) that PS would figure out what you meant. No dice.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Another option and possibly the more canonical way is to use curly braces to delineate the name:

```
$MyVariable = "Some text"
Write-Host "${MyVariable}NOSPACES"
```

This is particular handy for paths e.g. `${ProjectDir}Bin\$Config\Images`. However, if there is a `\` after the variable name, that is enough for PowerShell to consider that *not* part of the variable name.

Comment: How can I write this one: `Write-Host "\\"$pc[$i]`? I need 2 backslashes before a variable without spaces. This solution has one space between the second backslash and the var value.There should be a param like `-nonewlilne` for spaces.

Answer (score 28):

You need to wrap the variable in $()

For example, `Write-Host "$($MyVariable)NOSPACES"`

Comment: In my testing this put a space between the variable and the string literal.

Comment: This is what I see: `$MyVariable = "Some text"` `Write-Host "$($MyVariable)NOSPACES"` Some textNOSPACES

Comment: What is wrong? https://imgur.com/a/eLmBtlg Check that. There is no space between the variable text and the string literal.

Comment: Ultimately, I found I was inserting spaces through improper syntax, but first I jumped on Keith's answer - and it didn't work.  It works if $MyVariable contains a String, but not if it contains an Object with a Property storing the String; ${ObjectVariable.SomeProperty} resolves to nothing  This answer works for Object Properties too.

Answer (score 14):

```
Write-Host $MyVariable"NOSPACES"
```

Will work, although it looks very odd... I'd go for:

```
Write-Host ("{0}NOSPACES" -f $MyVariable)
```

But that's just me...

Comment: I always prefer the second option. I too thought it was just me :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can also use a back tick `` ` `` as below:

```
Write-Host "$MyVariable`NOSPACES"
```

Comment: This variant has an advantage that it works also within a command executed from the script (unlike `${MyVariable}` and `$($MyVariable)`)

Comment: This variant also has the disadvantage that if the character following the backtick matches a [special character](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_special_characters?view=powershell-6), it will insert that special character (try ``"$MyVariable`nospaces"``, for example).

Answer (score 2):

$Variable1 ='www.google.co.in/'

$Variable2 ='Images'

Write-Output ($Variable1+$Variable2)

Comment: Further to the question, this is another simple way to concatenate 2 variables without space. Putting both variables as shown in the above example, the output will be "www.google.co.in/images"

Answer (score 1):

Easiest solution: `Write-Host $MyVariable"NOSPACES"`

Comment: It works, but PowerShell will not let you insert multiple spaces between the variable and the string literal.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just move the spaces *to* the string literal? `Write-Host $MyVariable"   NOSPACES"`?

Comment: `$MyVariable = "x"`... $MyVariable"NOSPACES" --> x NOSPACES`. <-- inserts a space. This works --> `($MyVariable"NOSPACES")`

Answer (score 0):

if speed matters...

```
$MyVariable = "Some text"

# slow:
(measure-command {foreach ($i in 1..1MB) {
    $x = "$($MyVariable)NOSPACE"
}}).TotalMilliseconds

# faster:
(measure-command {foreach ($i in 1..1MB) {
    $x = "$MyVariable`NOSPACE"
}}).TotalMilliseconds

# even faster:
(measure-command {foreach ($i in 1..1MB) {
    $x = [string]::Concat($MyVariable, "NOSPACE")
}}).TotalMilliseconds

# fastest:
(measure-command {foreach ($i in 1..1MB) {
    $x = $MyVariable + "NOSPACE"
}}).TotalMilliseconds
```